# Can a user connect to the same VPN more than once simultaneously?

Tags: vpn

I do not have much knowledge of VPN (concepts, implementation specifics and what not). In general, to networking as well. So please correct me if my question doesn't make sense.

Is it possible that a VPN user, (let's say using different VPN clients) connects to the same VPN more than once (using same credentials) simultaneously?

Comment: This is not a security question sir

Comment: If the client is well configurated to do it and is not restricted on the server side, it could be totally possible. Server side it could be not allowed in many ways (it could allow only a single connection, or provide a fixed IP address to each user, so the second connection would drop the first one). Do note I am not posting as an answer because it last the security point, perhaps you want to consider posting in superuser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would totally depend on the VPN server software and its configuration. On some, it can work (I use it with my OpenVPN setup quite often), but for example when static IP addresses are assigned to users, it won't work. Also, it may just be a policy on the VPN server to allow just one login per account.

Comment: Interestingly, I OpenVPN is what I want to know about, thanks. I am parsing the generated syslogs, Is there a way to distinguish between these attempts? As I see them, there are multiple logs for an attempt, and there is no information tying those logs to exact attempts, especially if there can be multiple attempts from the same user, same remote IP occurring in near vicinity of time. If one of them fails, the logs don't have any tunnel/VPN IPs, so it's difficult to associate that attempt to any other logs if there are more than one.

Comment: @0xc0de This comment is much more in topic rather than the original question, I would sugggest you editing your question and focusing it on the syslog suspicious data so others can have a look and give you feedback of the scenario

Comment: @bradbury9 I agree, will post it as a separate question, possibly on a more suitable stack exchange site.

Comment: The "is possible to get two connections?" has already been answered, but the syslog analysis could fit this site.